# After form-source installation of Python2.7.9 I get ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl

I am using CentOS 6.6. and therefore I don't have newest (2.7 series) packages for Python which I need. I have installed Python 2.7.9 from source to /usr/local/lib/python2.7 :

```
ll /usr/local/lib/python2.7/
total 52K
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4.0K Jan 13 14:59 bin
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4.0K Jan  7 15:15 include
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4.0K Jan  7 15:15 lib
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  12K Jan 14 11:46 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  117 Jan 14 11:46 MANIFEST.in
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  238 Jan 14 11:46 NOTICE.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   88 Jan 14 11:46 setup.cfg
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.6K Jan 14 11:46 setup.py
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4.0K Jan  7 15:15 share
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4.0K Jan  7 15:03 site-packages
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  113 Jan 14 11:46 tox.ini
```

Now I have a script using [pysphere](https://code.google.com/p/pysphere/) and it used to work ok (and it works ok on other machines with 2.6 and 2.7) but when I ran it with my current setup I get this:

```
$ python main.py
Connecting to vSphere...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    server.connect(VSPHERE_IP, VSPHERE_USER, VSPHERE_PASS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysphere/vi_server.py", line 101, in connect
    request)._returnval
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysphere/resources/VimService_services.py", line 2170, in RetrieveServiceContent
    self.binding.Send(None, None, request, soapaction="urn:vim25/5.0", **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysphere/ZSI/client.py", line 295, in Send
    self.local.h.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1212, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 350, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 566, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 788, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)

$ pip -V
pip 6.0.6 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip freeze
Django==1.7.2
docutils==0.12
ecdsa==0.11
paramiko==1.15.2
pep8==1.5.7
pycrypto==2.6.1
Pygments==2.0.1
pysphere==0.1.7
pyvmomi==5.5.0.2014.1.1
requests==2.5.1
six==1.9.0
virtualenv==12.0.5
```

What is broken here ?

Comment: I have same problem with Docker fig tool https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/890  ...I also believe problem arose when I installed Python 2.7.9 ...they changed some stuff with SSL

Comment: someone here with same problem also using pysphere http://bugs.python.org/issue23052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a couple of years late to the party, but I just ran into this problem myself, and found **a** solution.  I'm leaving a comment should anyone in the future stumble across this thread.

The *reason* why this is happening (which was Patryk's question), is that Python's [httplib.HTTPSConnection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPSConnection) previously did not validate SSL certificates by default.  From Python 2.7.9 onwards, [SSL validation is required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28052583).  If your ESX server has some problem with its SSL certificate, the connection will fail.

Unfortunately [the pysphere library is no longer maintained](https://github.com/argos83/pysphere/commit/0829ccbe4ef3de6d9222c3a9e3cd9be0543887d6#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8).

Assuming that you are trying to use the pysphere library in a private and secure environment, you may apply the following patch to the pysphere/ZSI/client.py file:

```
294c294,295
<         self.local.h = transport(netloc, None, **self.transdict)
---
>         import ssl
>         self.local.h = transport(netloc, None, context=ssl._create_unverified_context(), **self.transdict)
```

**Explanation**: The pysphere library uses `httplib.HTTPSConnection` to establish a connection to the ESX server.  If it encounters an SSL certificate problem, it fails with the abovementioned exception.  To reinstate the behaviour prior to Python 2.7.9, you need to tell `httplib.HTTPSConnection` to not validate the SSL certificate.

Comment: Awesome! :) I do not use the code mentioned above anymore but it might be useful for someone else. Thanks!